# Checkout a specific folder from git using jenkins groovy "checkout" command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm pretty new to jenkins and groovy and I'm trying to do a sparse checkout in my jenkins file. Currently I simply do this:

```
stage('Check out branch from Gitlab'){ 
    echo 'Pulling...' + env.BRANCH_NAME
    checkout scm
}
```

I wish to execute a sparse checkout from a Jenkins Groovy script and I'm struggling to find a good way of doing this. Is there a way of using the "checkout" command to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure a set of parameters for the GitSCM [more info here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/)

A basic configuration is presented as an example below:

```
pipeline { 
    agent any
    stages {     
        stage ("Git Checkout"){ 
            steps {
            script {
                    checkout([
                        $class: 'GitSCM',
                        branches: [[name: "devel"]],
                        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                        extensions: [[
                            $class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                            relativeTargetDir: "/tmp/jenkins/devel"
                        ]],
                        submoduleCfg: [],
                        userRemoteConfigs: [[
                            credentialsId: 'jenkinsCredentialsId',
                            url: 'https://git.example.com/git/example'
                        ]]
                    ])
                
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I attached a fully working Jenkins pipeline of one stage. It checks out the branch `devel` of the repository `https://git.example.com/git/example` on directory `/tmp/jenkins/devel`. Also please note that you should add (if not already done) the credentials of the repository in Jenkins Credentials (/jenkins/credentials/), in the above example is under id `jenkinsCredentialsId`

You can read the link for GitSCM to find out more details and attributes that you can configure.